# How to fix it "No module named 'leven'" in jupyter note book

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Code:

```
from leven import levenshtein 
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import dbscan 

data = ["ACCTCCTAGAAG","ACCTACTAGAAGTT","GAATATTAGGCCGA"]

def lev_metric(x,y):
    i,j = int (x,y) , int (y[0])    # extract indices 
    return levenshtein(data[i],data[j])

X = np.arange(len(data)).reshape(-1,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, because you didn't install `leven`
Run these commands in Jupyter Notebook

```py
!pip install cython
!pip install leven
from leven import levenshtein
```

[Source](https://pypi.org/project/leven/)